# Oracle FK constraints are not enforced

Tags: foreign-keys, oracle12c

I'm using oracle 12c database and want to test out one problem.

When carrying out web service request it returns underlying ORA-02292 error on constraint name (YYY.FK_L_TILSYNSOBJEKT_BEGRENSNING). 
Here is SQL of the table with the constraint:

```
 CONSTRAINT "FK_L_TILSYNSOBJEKT_BEGRENSNING" FOREIGN KEY ("BEGRENSNING")
  REFERENCES "XXX"."BEGRENSNING" ("IDSTRING") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED ENABLE NOVALIDATE
```

The problem is, that when I try to delete the row manually with valid IDSTRING (in both tables) from **parent** table - it successfully does it.

What cause it to behave this way? Is there any other info I should give?

Comment: Pls define "successfully does it".  I note that your constraints are deferrable and indeed initially deferred.

Comment: @ErwinSmout  - well, it simply deletes the row, but the thing is that I don't really understand what deferring does. Reading up on it now

Comment: `initially deferred` means that the constraint should only be checked at the end of every **transaction**, not necessarily after each **statement**. This generally means you can have `DELETE`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE` etc., and the constraint is only checked when you issue `COMMIT` (or equivalent, such as executing a DDL statement or disconnecting from your session). Are you saying that the `DELETE` was "successful" in that it also survived `COMMIT`? That would be odd.

Comment: yeah, so this whole this messed up for me. Underlying cause was that i was used to auto commits and didnt know properly what deferred means (actually i read about it but didnt understand properly). That resulted in these deference constraints not being enforced when i THOUGHT i was commiting although I was actually just running query and never ended up commiting it, hence all the confusion =] anyways thanks for pointing out deference. you can put it in the answers

Comment: Why not post & accept an answer?

Comment: @philipxy, that's some strange new way of answering SO questions these days - to answer via comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it helps someone, since it was fairly stupid mistake, but i'll try to make it useful since people demand answers.

Keyword `DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED` means that constraint is enforced at **commit** not at query run time as opposed to `INITIALLY IMMEDIATE`, which does the check right after you issue the query, however this keyword makes database bulk updates a bit slower (since every query in a transaction has to be checked by constraint, meanwhile in initial deference if it turns out there is an issue - whole bulk is rolled back, no additional unnecessary queries are issued and something can be done about it), hence used less often than initial deference.

Error ORA-02292 however is shown only for `DELETE` statements, knowing that its a bit easier to debug your statements.